# How to check table

Tags: sql-server, mysql, permissions

How to check which tables a user have access to on a server?

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Big difference

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server version of 'check which tables a user have access' (Database Specific)

```
SELECT  [UserName] = princ.[name],
        [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
        [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
        [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
                         WHEN 1 THEN obj.type_desc -- Schema-contained objects 
                         ELSE perm.[class_desc] -- Higher-level objects 
                       END,
        [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
                         WHEN 1 THEN OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) -- General objects 
                         WHEN 3 THEN schem.[name] -- Schemas 
                         WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name] -- Impersonations 
                       END 
FROM    sys.database_principals princ --database user 
        LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals ulogin ON princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]  --Login accounts 
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]  --Permissions
        LEFT JOIN sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas schem ON schem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id] 
--WHERE princ.[name] = 'UserName' and obj.name='TableName'
WHERE  obj.type_desc= 'USER_TABLE'
ORDER BY [ObjectType],[ObjectName],perm.[permission_name]
```